# Subject-verb agreement for property of the items of a list

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Consider the sentence

> The cavity of each device A, B, and C was/were ...

where each device has only one cavity. Cavity is singular, but it is applied to each of the items of a list. How should one decide to use the singular or plural here?

An alternative form of the sentence is

> The cavities of devices A, B, and C were ...

However, it seems that this form leaves ambiguous whether each device has one or more cavities. Would either form be satisfactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singular subject alone determines demands a singular verb, especially in American English.  "The cavity of each was explored."  The separation of the singular subject from the verb by a long phrase ending with a plural noun is an old English-teacher trick because it "sounds OK" to someone who does not immediately recognize the structure of the sentence.  Parse away the modifiers and the answer is clear.  "Cavity was explored."